# how solve ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The error MX records are:

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, mx-record, ptr-record

i have remote access to my windows server 2008 r2(DNS-IIS-FTP-MAIL),
please see the link below for my web site :
http://www.intodns.com/polyafzar.com

how can i fix the error below in my server :

> ERROR: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are:
>   234.60.7.31.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
>   233.60.7.31.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected
>   You should contact your ISP and ask   him to add a PTR record for your ips

thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like it's not a problem on your machine: it's a limitation of the destination SMTP server that will refuse mail if you haven't setup an rDNS record.

Comment: hi Stephane, so is it necessary to add some new records into my dns or not(or change something in my dns)? besides i did n't install SMTP Server Feature in my server(is there any relationship between that error and this feature?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like it says:

> "You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your
>   ips"

You have to get whomever looks after your hosting to provide rDNS records in order to eliminate this error.

Comment: thanks for attention | so, can i do something by myself in remote server or not?

Comment: "You should contact your ISP and ask him to add a PTR record for your ips". Are you your ISP? If so, you can do it. If not, then you need to do what the instructions say :)

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DigitalOcean VPS, the solution is this below:

Reverse DNS (PTR) records are automatically created based on the name that you give your droplet in the Control Panel. If you want to rename a droplet, go to its page in the Control Panel, click directly on the existing Droplet name, and enter a new name there.

There are two things to keep in mind. That new name has to be a fully-qualified domain name - that means that example.com will generate a valid PTR record, but a name like my-ubuntu-droplet will not generate a PTR record. Also, if you're using IPv6 on your droplet, a PTR record will only be generated for the first IPv6 address assigned to the droplet, not all 16 IPv6 addresses which are available to the droplet.

I hope it helps!